# OpenVPN Allow clients to acess more machines

Tags: firewall, openvpn, windows-server-2019

Currently, my OpenVPN Windows Server (192.168.15.56) only allows connection to itself and Firewall is disabled entirely for now. In my ISP Router I have a rule that allows remote connections for all IPs in the VPN port.

I want to allow clients to acess the IP 192.168.15.169 too (or the entire LAN, whatever). My config files:

**client.ovpn:**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

remote <dns> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
disable-dco

mssfix 1420
comp-lzo
verb 4
```

**server.ovpn:**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

server 10.20.30.0 255.255.255.0

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

route   192.168.15.0   255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.15.169 255.255.255.255"
push "route 192.168.15.56 255.255.255.255"
push "route 192.168.15.0 255.255.255.0"

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4
```

**tracert 192.168.15.169:**

```
  1    49 ms    38 ms    38 ms  WIN-3RHODPCQ0MO [10.20.30.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request Time out
```

10.20.30.1 is my server vpn ip, but I can ping 192.168.15.56 (Private IP) with no problem, I would like to do the same to 169.

Comment: welcome, home and enduser question are offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com instead

Comment: Routing has to be bi-directional. That means that `.169` needs a route back to the VPN client. This can go through the default route, or a separate routing table entry.

Comment: @vidarlo How do I route back in `.169`? Is the config done in the Server itself? How do I add this table entry in Windows?

Comment: You probably should look into having whatever device is your default gateway do that then. How? Read applicable documentation.

Comment: @vidarlo thank you! I will look into it.